# error JS: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, symfony

I work with Symfony in backend (I create controller when I return data invoque in database) .. now with Ajax I have invoqu data return in controller but I have this error:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Code controller:

```
<?php

        namespace Tag\TagBundle\Controller;

        use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
        use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
        class TagController extends Controller
        {

            /**
             *@ param Request $request
             */
            public function indexAction(Request $request) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $rep = $em->getRepository('TagBundle:Tag')->findAll();
                    return $this->json($rep,200,[],['groups' => ['public']]);
            }
        }
```

Code JS:

```
    $( function() {
       $.ajax({
           url:Routing.generate('tags'),
           type:'post',
           cache:false,
           success: function(data,response){
            var data = JSON.parse('data'); 
            console.log(data);
               $( ".bootstrap-tagsinput > input" ).autocomplete({
        source: data
      });

          }
       });

    } );
```

Comment: remove the `'` around data: `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: you probably don't even need to `JSON.parse()` your data if its already returning JSON, only parse if it returns  `String` and you want it to be JSON.

Comment: data.toString() !!! with this code  @MrNew

Comment: @devit2017, sorry I don't follow. if you want JSON to be `String` you can use `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: @MrNew, okey good my friend but now I have this result: [{"name":"med"},{"name":"dev"},{"name":"demo"},{"name":""},{"name":"test"},{"name":"nbg"},{"name":"symfony"},{"name":"coding"},{"name":"dev-web"},{"name":"dem"}] ... how to use name !! how to give result array["med","dev","demo" ...] !! thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't really follow what you're trying to do, can you amend your question with what you're trying to do or create a new question.

Comment: You probably don't need to write `$.ajax` at all. jQuery Autocomplete can use a URL as a source. It will perform the AJAX request by itself and parse the response.